# Why I get "cannot unpack" error with PythonNet but not with IronPython?

Tags: python, c#, ironpython

I tried to connect to socket with `IronPython` and everything worked. But, when I try with `Python.Runtime` I get `Python.Runtime.PythonException: 'cannot unpack non-iterable ValueTuple[String,Int32] object'` exception. I use `PythonRuntime` for `python3.8`

**Python.Runtime**

```
Runtime.PythonDLL = "python38.dll";
PythonEngine.Initialize();

dynamic socketModule = Py.Import("socket");
dynamic clientSocket = socketModule.create_connection(("127.0.0.1", 30001));
```

**IronPython**

```
ScriptRuntime ipy = IronPython.Hosting.Python.CreateRuntime();
dynamic sys = ipy.ImportModule("sys");
sys.path.append(@"C:\Python34\lib");

dynamic socketModule = ipy.ImportModule("socket");
```

Comment: How is this related to C#?

Comment: What do you mean? The code is in C#